# How to better analyze contents of a `call`?

Tags: r, parsing

In the package `rootSolve`,  the function `multiroot`  requires an input argument which is a collection of functions.  I found a way to determine dynamically how many functions are contained in that input argument, but would like some help from the `R` community as to a cleaner approach.  The example input function here (underdefined, but that doesn't matter so far as parsing it goes)

```
 Kfunc<-function(x) {
    z<-c( z1<- 4*var1 -3*var2 +5*var3, z2<-8*var1 +5*var2 -2*var3   )
}
```

Where the `z1,z2,z3` are the outputs and "varJ" are the parameters to be determined

I came up with this stack of functions to find out how many separate functions are "inside" the definition of `z` :

```
bar <- parse(text = (parse(text = body(Kfunc)[2] )[[1]][3]))
length(bar[[1]])
#[1] 3
 bar[[1]][1]
#c()
 bar[[1]][2]
#(z1 <- 4 * var1 - 3 * var2 + 5 * var3)()
bar[[1]][3]
#(z2 <- 8 * var1 + 5 * var2 - 2 * var3)()
```

Showing that the number of equations is equal to `length(bar[[1]]) - 1`

Is there a faster/shorter/cleaner way,  preferably without requiring a non-base library?

Comment: I like to use the https://github.com/r-lib/lobstr package library(lobstr)


ast(function(x) {
  z <- c(z1 <- 4 * var1 - 3 * var2 + 5 * var3,
         z2 <- 8 * var1 + 5 * var2 - 2 * var3)
}
)

Comment: you could use `utils::getParseData`, but those variables aren't functions

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is, but perhaps a cleaner approach would be to attach metadata to objects that will be passed as functions.  I agree using `parse(text` like this is not a clean approach in general.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I have a wrapper function `ktsolve` which accepts inputs designed for different solver packages, including `rootSolve` and `BB` . The format of the function (set of equations) differs between packages; my goal is to check that the number of "unknown" input variables and number of equations is the same and issue warnings if it isn't.  As such I need to figure out "on the fly" how many equations are inside the submitted function.

Comment: it sounds like you might be able to use a wrapper class to hold the number of equations.  Since the formats differ they could inherit from the same base class, allowing for differences, but the equations could still be retrievable via the same accessor methodds